# Find the probability of taking a white ball.

Tags: probability

We are given 50 white balls in box one, 10 white balls and 10 black balls in box 2. A ball is chosen at random. What is the probability of getting a white ball?

Initially we can approach this in the easiest way.

First Approach.

70 balls in total with 60 of them being white balls. Hence, $\frac{6}{7}$

However, I thought this might be looked at this way as well.

Second Approach.

Equal chance of taking a ball from box 1 and box 2, (that is 50% each). If we take from box 1, then the probability of getting a white ball is 100%. If we take from box 2, then the probability of getting a white ball is 50% ($\frac{1}{2}$). We have (50%)(50%) + (100%)(50%) = 75%

Im not quite sure which approach should I take.

Comment: Sorry....how many boxes are there?  If there only two, why label the second one $\#10$?  If there are $10$ or more, what is the color distribution in all the others?

Comment: To your question, regardless of the details regarding the boxes, the ambiguity arises because you don't make it clear how you are selecting a ball.  Presumably, you first choose a box (uniformly at random).  Then you choose a ball (uniformly at random) from the chosen urn.

Comment: Apologies. That was a mistake in my part. Fixed it.

Comment: No problem.  In that case, as I said, you need to be clear about how you are choosing the ball.  If, as I suspect, you first choose a box and then choose the ball, then your second approach is the way to go.

Comment: @lulu I do agree with you. But I suppose it is an exam question so I don't think I can do much.

Comment: What is the prob. of choosing either box?

Comment: In that case, I'd go ahead and assume that the mechanism is what I said.  Your first method assumes each ball is equally likely...to achieve that, you;d need to throw all the balls together before choosing.  I think that would be a strange way to read the problem.

Comment: Note:  in any case, if you are making assumptions be sure to specify them clearly.  A lot of confusion is generated by being vague about the details.

Comment: I suppose if we use the first approach, the information that they are put in the different boxes should be of no effect.

Comment: That is exactly right.  Like I say, the easiest way (I can think of) to make each ball equally likely is to throw all the balls together in one box.  Perfectly possible but, as I say, a strange reading of the problem.